# Most secure way too store passwords in php

Tags: php, variables, session-variables, password-encryption

I am just wondering if this is secure to use. (storing the openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() in a variable)

```
$pass = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(96);
```

Because some of you say that I should not store passwords in variables!

Comment: For password storage, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) and **DO NOT** store passwords in sessions or cookies for that matter.

Comment: No I want too generate password in php therefore I need this answer

Comment: You should clarify what the passwords are for.

Comment: Why? But if you are so currius... The password is for AES encryption

Comment: @tor Because you should almost never store a password in PHP...

Comment: Read the question again, hope you will understand now

Comment: I suggest moving it/posting it in code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and/or security exchange http://security.stackexchange.com/ you may get a better response there. Stack deals mostly with code that doesn't work. This is far too broad a subject here.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will check them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use Blowfish. It is very secure and comes with PHP!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

It's simple and every server with PHP has it - the only downside, like other advanced encryption methods - it *could* be slow. But I wouldn't worry.

**EDIT**

I read your edit and yes, I don't think storing passwords, especially hashed, in a _SESSION or variable because there is no reason to. If you did, what if someone used an attack that stlole one of your clients sessions? Their password would be stolen. Also, the openssl method you're mentioning has OpenSSL under the hood, meaning that it is just as vulnerable as OpenSSL itself. OpenSSL went through some serious flaws in the past, and that might happen again.

Just store the encrypted password in a DB and you'll be fine.

**EDIT 3**

I read your comment, I didn't know this was the page you were using to encrypt and store the passwords. We all were thinking you were storing the passwords in the page just because. If you use this plus the Blowfish and store the password in the DB it will be secure. I think you only have to worry about someone stealing the DB, but they will have to have a lot of resources to decrypt a blowfish alone if the password is string enough.

You are doing a good job, just add the blowfish and you'll be good.

Comment: Read the question again, hope you will understand now

Comment: But I need to have it in php so I can encrypt with AES then store the pass hased!

Comment: This answer is even more confused than the original question.